# Can we remove Arrow Helper object by clicking on it?

Tags: three.js

I know we can remove any object by `scene.__removeObject()`
So I am removing any object in the screen by using raycaster. When I click on a object `intersects.length` becomes >0 and `scene.__removeObject(SELECTED)` gets executed. But if click on an `Arrowhelper` object (say `ARROW`) `intersects.length` is still zero.

So how I remove the Arrow helper from GUI. In code I know `scene.__removeObject(ARROW)` works

```
function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

        event.preventDefault();

        var vector = new THREE.Vector3( mouse.x, mouse.y, 0.5 );
        projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );

        var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );

        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects );

        if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

            controls.enabled = false;

            SELECTED = intersects[ 0 ].object;
           scene.__removeObject(SELECTED)
           // scene.__removeObject(ARROW)


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in fact about intersections, correct ?

The ArrowHelper is made of two meshes [.cone](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/helpers/ArrowHelper.js#L37) and [.line](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/helpers/ArrowHelper.js#L32) so it should be intersectable just like other objects.

Remember the Raycaster will only intersect objects that are in your `objects` variable.

I see two solutions for your problem:

- make sure the `objects` variable contains the helper's `.cone` or `.line` or both.
- add the whole helper in `objects` (`objects.push(ARROW)`) but then you have to call `intersectObjects` [recursively](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Raycaster.js#L373)

  raycaster.intersectObjects( objects, true );